# Как устроена работа буферизации в php?

Tags: php, буферизация

***Существует 2 вида буферов в php:***

1. Cистемный буфер
2. Пользовательский буфер

Так могут возникнуть проблемы с работой с буфером.
Для работы с системным буфером есть одна единственная функция - `flush()`. Для работы с пользовательским буфером остальные функции с приставкой `ob_`(Функция `ob_implicit_flush()` - не относится к данному списку, она больше подходит к системному буферу).

**Код для демонстрации:**

> Внимание использована инструкция в файле **.htaccess**
>   `php_value output_buffering off`

```
<?php
echo "LVL of buffer: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i.":(".mt_rand(0,1000).") ";
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo "<br>LVL of buffer: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
header("Hello");
session_start();
header("Support title");
echo "<h3>Thx!</h3>";
?>
```

Этим примером я хотел показать что при использовании только системного буфера мы можем выводить кусочками сообщение на экран. Минусом является то что если захотим отправить заголовки или сессию то будет ошибка, т.к после отправки первого сообщения на экран всевозможные заголовки были отправлены и повторная передача заголовков невозможна.

**Код для демонстрации - 2:**

> Внимание использована инструкция в файле **.htaccess**
>   `php_value output_buffering 4096`

```
<?php
echo "LVL of buffer: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i.":(".mt_rand(0,1000).") ";
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo "<br>LVL of buffer: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
header("Hello");
session_start();
header("Support title");
echo "<h3>Thx!</h3>";
?>
```

В этом примере мы не увидим кусочный вывод текста мы увидем его только когда исполнится весь код. Даже `flush()` здесь не поможет. Здесь между прочим используется не только системный, но и пользовательский буфер. Кстати вылезут ошибочки по поводу заголовков...тут конечно я не могу объяснить ситуацию из-за чего. Я в конце выскажу свои предположения и вопросы...stay here.

**Код для демонстрации - 3:**

> Внимание использована инструкция в файле **.htaccess**
>   `php_value output_buffering 4096`

```
<?php
echo "LVL of buffer: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i.":(".mt_rand(0,1000).") ";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo "<br>LVL of buffer: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
header("Hello");
session_start();
header("Support title");
echo "<h3>Thx!</h3>";
?>
```

В этом примере информация будет выводиться кусками. Этот пример как вы могли заметить отличается только дополнительной функцией `ob_flush()`. Она таки высвобождает накопленные данные в системный буфер. Следом вызывается `flush()` который информацию выводит прямо в браузер. Первый пример кода тому явное подтверждение. В конце будут отправлены ошибки о заголовках, оно и понятно данные были уже отправлены.

**Код для демонстрации - 4:**

> Внимание использована инструкция в файле **.htaccess**
>   `php_value output_buffering off`

```
<?php
echo "LVL of buffer: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i.":(".mt_rand(0,1000).") ";
    sleep(1);
}
echo "<br>LVL of buffer: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
header("Hello");
session_start();
header("Support title");
echo "<h3>Thx!</h3>";
?>
```

Интересно, а для чего я этот код добавил? Никаких флюшей здесь нет, даже функций, которые работают с буфером вывода. Все гораздо проще чем может показаться на первый взгляд. Дело в том что если мы запустим этот код он отработает как надо и выведет ошибки об уже отправленных заголовках...what? Выходит системный буфер не такой и буфер если он вызывает ошибку о заголовках, однако данные выведутся только тогда когда закончится скрипт. Вот так вот.

**Эпилог:**

**Мои суждения:**

1. Т.к существует 2 буфера в php то получается один зависит от другого: чтобы вывести информацию со свежевыпеченного echo, мы должны сначала высвободить информацию с "нашего" буфера в "казенный" php буфер, после этого мы должны вызвать операцию для "казенного" php буфера на вывод.
2. Системный буфер нельзя удалить, а пользовательский можно.
3. Информация всегда будет попадать в системный буфер хочешь ты того или нет!
4. Пользовательский буфер - это станция где люди ожидают свой самолет. Системный буфер - это самолет, который вмещает в себя людей. Заголовки - это купленные билеты (Вы же не можете купить билет уже в самолете (Ну по крайней мере я ни разу такого не видел)), если самолет имеет время ожидания вы можете купить билет прямо на станции. Одно без другого жить не может, нет пользовательского буфера - нет времени для покупки билета, нет системного буфера - нет самолета. Выводом буфера будет являться то, когда самолет прибудет на станцию и высадит пассажиров

**Вопросы:**

1. Мой второй пример, мне не понятно по какой причине мне в конце работы скрипта php пишет ошибку, по факту `flush()` не срабатывает ввиду того что мы находимся в пользовательском буфере. (Хотя возможно то что в системном буфере ничего нет и этим вызовом мы уже отправляем заголовки)
2. Если опять же во втором примере мы заменим `flush()` => `ob_flush()`, мы получим ошибки об отправленных заголовках...why? Как я писал есть 2 буфера системный и пользовательский, по логике в системном буфере лежит пользовательский и как вы могли видеть при наличии пользовательского буфера необходимо вызвать 2 флюша, а если у нас имелся только системный то хватало системного флюша.
3. Если мы в файле .htaccess напишем `php_value output_buffering on` то размер буфера станет unlimited как сообщает `php.ini`, отнюдь если мы в скрипте вызовем функцию `ob_get_level()` то получим 0, если вы запускали код, который я писал выше то могли заметить если у нас буфер был заданного размера то мы получали 1, если мы его удаляли или писали off то он у нас был 0 (хочу заметить я знаю что могут быть вложенные буферы и значение может быть куда выше)...собственно почему у нас 0 если размер буфера on?

---

**Переосмысление (ответы на первый, второй и третий вопросы):**

1. Если данные попадают в системный буфер то заголовки будут отправлены, не важно вызвали вы `flush()` или нет,
   как следствие - варн об от отправленных заголовках*
2. Если вы вызовете `flush()`, но в системный буфер до этого ничего не попадало, это будет означать что данные 
   нужно вывести на экран немедленно из системного буфера, как следствие - отправка заголовков и варн*
3. Если вы пишите `ob_flush()` в пользовательском буфере с уровнем < 2 (это равносильно тому, что если вы пишите `echo` 
   в системном буфере), то вы получите варн* так как вы пробрасываете содержимое в системный буфер, а как я писал выше
   системный буфер если видит какие-то выводимые данные он начинает отправлять заголовки, в этом случае происходит
   то же самое.
4. Если мы в файле `.htaccess` напишем `php_value output_buffering on` при вызове `phpinfo()` в php файле мы увидим в колонке `Local Value - on`. В итоге у нас буфер 0! Как так? Все просто. Эта директива (output_buffering) не поддерживает такое значение. У этой директивы есть несколько состояний: 0 - выключенный буфер, 1 - безлимитный буфер и любое число. Кроме того если мы напишем текст вроде: `on`, `off`, `true`, `false`, `sampletext` - то в `Local Value` мы увидим подобные значения, но они будут интерпетироваться как 0. Если мы будем писать текст через пробел то получим ошибку 500, например `php_value output_buffering hello world`.

`*` Если вы отправляете заголовки после.

`**` `php_value`, `php_flag`, `output_buffering` - директивы.

P.S Возможно я что-то не правильно понял, не стоит воспринимать это как истину, в любом случае я смог понять только так, по-другому объяснить свои вопросы не удалось. В любом случае я жду объяснения от людей, которые соображают

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу только на часть вашего вопроса, по крайней мере на текущий момент.

Ваш код:

```
<?php
echo "LVL of buffer: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i.":(".mt_rand(0,1000).") ";
    sleep(1);
}
echo "<br>LVL of buffer: ".ob_get_level()."<br>";
header("Hello");
session_start();
header("Support title");
echo "<h3>Thx!</h3>";
?>
```

Ваш комментарий к нему:

> Интересно, а для чего я этот код добавил? Никаких флюшей здесь нет,
>   даже функций, которые работают с буфером вывода. Все гораздо проще чем
>   может показаться на первый взгляд. Дело в том что если мы запустим
>   этот код он отработает как надо и выведет ошибки об уже отправленных
>   заголовках...what? Выходит системный буфер не такой и буфер если он
>   вызывает ошибку о заголовках, однако данные выведутся только тогда
>   когда закончится скрипт. Вот так вот.

Так вот. Не совсем понятно, почему вы в этом, четвертом примере решили (если я вас верно понял), почему не должно быть предупреждений насчет заголовков. Так или иначе, вы в любом случае должны послать их самыми первыми, до посыла всяких там текстовых сообщений через `echo` - банально потому, что именно такого поведения от веб-сервера ожидают браузеры. И `php` тут просто уведомляет вас, что вы неверно пытаетесь сообщить браузеру что-либо через заголовки.

Для понимания этого стоит обратиться к собственно протоколу `HTTP`, а именно к его структуре. Ответ веб-сервера в общем случае состоит из трех частей: `Starting line`, `Headers` и `Message Body`. Первое отвечает за тип сообщения, второе за заголовки и третье собственно за то, что получит браузер в качестве ответа.

Соответственно, когда приведенный код выше начинает выполняться, вне зависимости от того, играетесь ли вы с буфером или нет, веб-сервер, который работает с вашим интерпретатором `php`, будь он `apache`'ем или чем угодно еще, при получении от `php` первого же текстового сообщения в третьей строке вашего кода (а оно будет первым, данный код же будет выполняться последовательно), сформирует ответ браузеру, который будет состоять из трех перечисленных выше частей. И далее веб-браузер может всего лишь досылать что-либо в `Message Body`, но заголовки уже будут отправлены.

Другими словами, если вы хотите что-то вывести в заголовках, то вам нужно сформировать их до первого любого вывода в браузер, или же выстроить логику своего приложения каким-либо иным образом, где функция `header()` не будет использоваться после любой функции, реализующей вывод чего бы то ни было браузеру посредством `HTTP`.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы немного прояснить для себя и других, как работает буферизация в PHP, давайте заглянем в исходники. У меня исходники php-7.1.3.

Заходим в корневую папку исходников и пытаемся найти в них реализацию функции `ob_get_contents`:

```
$ fgrep -r 'PHP_FUNCTION(ob_get_contents)' .
```

Находится такое:

```
./main/output.c:PHP_FUNCTION(ob_get_contents)
```

Вот эта функция:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(ob_get_contents)
{
    if (zend_parse_parameters_none() == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    if (php_output_get_contents(return_value) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
}
```

(Попутно было замечено, что PHP-еретики в своих кодах используют табулятор вместо 4-х пробелов.)

В том же файле находим функцию `php_output_get_contents`:

```
PHPAPI int php_output_get_contents(zval *p)
{
    if (OG(active)) {
        ZVAL_STRINGL(p, OG(active)->buffer.data, OG(active)->buffer.used);
        return SUCCESS;
    } else {
        ZVAL_NULL(p);
        return FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Что происходит? Выглядит так, как будто что-то (видимо, возвращаемая строка) формируется на основе некоторого адреса в памяти и длины данных. То есть пользовательский буфер это просто кусок памяти. Вероятно, там еще есть стек меток для каждого вызова `ob_start`. Это уже сами ищите реализацию `ob_start`, кому интересно.

Аналогичным образом можно найти реализацию функции `flush` и увидеть, что она работает через функцию конкретного применяемого SAPI. Я посмотрел SAPI для PHP как модуля Apache:

```
static void
php_apache_sapi_flush(void *server_context)
{
    php_struct *ctx;
    request_rec *r;

    ctx = server_context;

    /* If we haven't registered a server_context yet,
     * then don't bother flushing. */
    if (!server_context) {
        return;
    }

    r = ctx->r;

    sapi_send_headers();

    r->status = SG(sapi_headers).http_response_code;
    SG(headers_sent) = 1;

    if (ap_rflush(r) < 0 || r->connection->aborted) {
        php_handle_aborted_connection();
    }
}
```

Здесь используются структуры C API самого Apache, то есть и вывод предварительно должен делаться таким же образом. Как Apache буферизует выводимые данные - это уже его личное дело и к PHP не имеет никакого отношения.

Результат таков, что "системная" и "пользовательская" буферизация в PHP - это абсолютно разные вещи, настолько разные, что их не стоило бы называть в одном списке, чтобы не вносить сумятицу, и, возможно, с той же целью, пользовательскую буферизацию вообще стоило бы назвать как-то по-другому.

Comment: Ну это вроде и так понятно было, автор как раз и пытается развести их между собой, просто не совсем удачно названия для них подобрал.